# Bootstrap cols do not stand in a row Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some problem with Angular components.
I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-item></app-item>
    <app-item></app-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside of `app-item` component i got this code:

```
<div class="col-6">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

I can't understand why those columns don't stand in row. It's actually one column under the second
But if i do like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then it's working fine. Why is my code not working out when i try to use components? What is the reason it happens?
Also for some reasons my component `app-item` has no 100% width
Can anyone explain me what's wrong?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @user184994 i think all current versions of browsers like opera, google chrome and so on

Comment: Okay. Are you able to move the `col-6` class onto the `app-item` tag instead?

Comment: @user184994 if i move the col-6 tag on component like this <app-item class="col-4"></app-item> and remove the col-4 class from component file. it works. But im not actually sure it's right way isnt it?

Comment: I believe the issue is that `flex` styling only applies to the immediate children, and in this case you have `app-item` in the way. There is the `display: contents` CSS rule, but it still has very limited browser support.

Comment: Just to add to the above, the Boostrap docs say `only columns may be immediate children of rows`, and in the original code they're *not* immediate children

Comment: @user184994 i understand it. Is there any way to remove app-item component from DOM? I mean only show what is inside this componenent and don't show component itself

Comment: Not that I can see...

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to include bootstrap library link :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plaese try the below,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <app-item></app-item>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <app-item></app-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside of app-item

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: Im sure it will work, but i need to dynamically take data from json, i don't know how much columns i have, that's a problem. Sometimes this way wont work

Answer (score 0):

This could be late but may help OP or someone else. I resolved it in a similar way, although I could have resolved it like @malindu mentioned because I knew how many `cols` would be there but it wasn't generic.

So if you pass the class directly to your `component` like the following code snippet and remove the `col-*` div from inside the component it works fine because now the `col` is direct child of the row. Check the code snippet below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-item class="col-6"></app-item>    <-------- check the class here
    <app-item class="col-6"></app-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then inside your component

```
<p>Some text</p>    <-------and then it is removed from inside here
```